# PowerBI: How to format data bars / cells based on deviation from the mean of each column?

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api, powerbi-desktop

I am working on moving a dashboard from Tableau to PowerBI, but I am struggling to find a way to color some of the cells / data bars relative to each other.

I have the margin of multiple products, and I want to compare it for different regions.  I want to highlight those regions performing well and those underperforming.

I want to achieve something similar to this tableau dashboard:

[image: Tableau dashboard with desired outome]

Where Profit % = SUM(Profit) / SUM(Sales)

and Color =

```
    IF ([Profit %]) > (WINDOW_AVG(([Profit %]))+0.75*WINDOW_STDEV(([Profit %]))) THEN "Green"
ELSEIF  ([Profit %]) < (WINDOW_AVG(([Profit %]))-0.75*WINDOW_STDEV(([Profit %]))) THEN "Red"
ELSE "Neutral"
END
```

In PowerBI, I have tried using a Matrix with "Region" in rows, "Category" in columns, and profit % in values. Where Profit % is calculated as

```
CALCULATE([Output], 'Table'[Type] = "Profit") / CALCULATE([Output], 'Table'[Type] = "Sales")
```

From there, I tried multiple approaches to color the cells but not are providing the desired / correct result.

```
VAR AvgProfit = AVERAGEX(ALLSELECTED(Table), [Profit %])
VAR StDevProfit = STDEVX(ALLSELECTED(Table), [Profit %])
VAR Threshold = 0.75

RETURN
    IF(
        [Profit %] > AvgProfit + Threshold * StDevProfit,
        "Green",
        IF(
            [Profit %] < AvgProfit - Threshold * StDevProfit,
            "Red",
            "Neutral"
        )
    )
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!